# Craft CMS: Remove matching/duplicate text from query results

Tags: craftcms

I have written a query to select all categories for a certain entry. In this case, the category is called "Key Stage" and each one is written "Key Stage 1", "Key Stage 2" etc. What I'd like to happen is that if more than one category is selected for the entry, the duplicated words "Key Stage" could be stripped out, leaving "Key Stage 1 & 2", instead of "Key Stage 1 & Key Stage 2".

Below is the code I have thus far, which is just the query and looping out the results, adding an ampersand for subsequent items in the loop after the first:

```
<p class="stage">
  <strong>
  {% for stage in eventKeyStage %}
  {% if not loop.first %}&amp; {% endif %}
  {{ stage.title }}
  {% endfor %}
  </strong>
</p>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with a hacky method, thought I'd post in the off chance it could be useful to someone else. Basically, I hard coded the "Key Stage" part and then just replaced the actual "Key Stage" text from the category with nothing. So the result looks like this:

```
{% set eventKeyStage = event.keyStage.all() %}
<p class="stage">
  <strong>
    Key Stage
    {% for stage in eventKeyStage %}
      {% if not loop.first %}&amp;{% endif %}
      {{ stage.title|replace({'Key Stage': ''}) }}
    {% endfor %}
  </strong>
</p>
```

Probably not the right way to do it, but it works!

Comment: Did you consider [my answer on Craft.SE](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/38601/11705)? Also, crossposting questions is discouraged on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind for next time! 
Yes this is fantastic, thanks so much for your help. I did come up with a hacky solution as you saw, but it has drawbacks. I completely get your point about the redundancy of repeating "Key Stage", however having thought about it I think the issue actually lies more with the name of the category. This would probably be better named "Suitability" - the category is for school stages. So going forward they could add others such as "Primary", therefore "Key stage" does need to be there otherwise you're just left with a number.
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Actually with the above in mind, your solution, while perfect for what I thought I needed, no longer works sadly. Basically it needs to check if "Key Stage" is there, and if it appears more than once, remove the duplicate words. And even in that case, it would need to put key stages together consecutively. Maybe it's just not doable!

Comment: Of course it's possible, it's just a matter of filtering and sorting the categories so they're in the order you need them to be to join the titles as mentioned. Check out the answer I linked above, I updated them with some pointers on how to filter and sort the query. If my answer works for you, would you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you so much for your time and help here. Sadly I posted the question as a guest and then created an account afterwards and it is not showing as my question, I have no idea how to claim it. I also can't comment or upvote due to lack of reputation score.

Comment: You're welcome! You can get accounts merged or guest questions added to your account, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332149/3167371

Comment: Thank you I have done so :)